# python 3 tkinter: Window does not show with OptionMenu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add a OptionMenu to a frame. If I add the OptionMenu, the window does not open any more. Without it works fine. It works like this:

```
self.tmp_var = tk.StringVar(self.frm_top)
self.tmp_list = self.get_templates()
self.tmp_list.insert(0, '-- Select a template ---')
self.tmp_var.set(self.tmp_list[0])
```

as soon I add

```
self.ddTemplates = tk.OptionMenu(self.frm_top, self.tmp_var, *self.tmp_list)
```

the window does not open again.
If I run the script from the command line I get
Gleitkomma-Ausnahme

Get the same same effect if I use an example from the web like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
root.title("tk.Optionmenu as combobox")
var = StringVar(root)
# initial value
var.set('red')
choices = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow','white', 'magenta']
option = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)
button = Button(root, text="check value slected")button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10))
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. You have to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the optionmenu for it to show up in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I declare all grid rows at one place in code, I overlooked the dynamically added row deeper down the in the code. Add the rowconfig to the grid solved the problem.